# Convert mediumtext to date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp-with-timezone

I have column data that stores date in mediumtext datatype. How do I convert mediumtext to date so I can extract data for certain time range.

Thank you

Sample data:

- Fri Sep 11 15:30:55 JST 2015
- Fri Sep 11 15:40:09 JST 2015
- Fri Sep 11 14:55:09 SGT 2015
- Fri Sep 11 14:57:38 SGT 2015
- Fri Sep 11 03:59:02 EDT 2015
- Fri Sep 11 01:10:17 PDT 2015

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Can you post your sample data as text instead of a screenshot?

Comment: Is the new screenshot helpful?

Comment: Use the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

Comment: Ensure your timezone data is loaded into MySQL first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use STR_TO_DATE function with appropriate format model. The function doesn't have a format model for handling the timezone abbreviation as part of the datetime string, so we have to do a bit of string manipulation to workaround it

e.g.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,' ',4),' ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,' ',-1)),'%a %b %d %T %Y') AS dt
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,' ',5),' ',-1) AS tz
  FROM ( SELECT 'Fri Sep 11 15:30:55 JST 2015' AS foo
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Fri Sep 11 15:40:09 JST 2015'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Fri Sep 11 14:55:09 SGT 2015'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Fri Sep 11 14:57:38 SGT 2015'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Fri Sep 11 03:59:02 EDT 2015'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Fri Sep 11 01:10:17 PDT 2015'
       ) t
```

To handle the timezone, we can use CONVERT_TZ function, but the mysql.time_zone_name (and related time_zone tables) need to be populated, to handle the values for timezone.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,' ',4),' ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,' ',-1)),'%a %b %d %T %Y') AS dt
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,' ',5),' ',-1) AS tz

     , CONVERT_TZ( STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,' ',4),' ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,' ',-1)),'%a %b %d %T %Y')
                 , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,' ',5),' ',-1)
                 , '+00:00'
       ) AS dt_utc
  FROM ( SELECT 'Fri Sep 11 01:10:17 PDT 2015' AS foo
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Fri Sep 11 01:10:17 PST8PDT 2015'
       ) t
```

returns

```
dt                   tz       dt_utc
-------------------  -------  -------------------
2015-09-11 01:10:17  PDT      (NULL)
2015-09-11 01:10:17  PST8PDT  2015-09-11 08:10:17
```

N.B.  If `mysql.time_zone_name` table doesn't contain entries for `PDT`, `EDT`, `SGT` or other tz values that we want to convert, the `CONVERT_TZ` function will return NULL.

---

FOLLOWUP

Using these types of expressions in the WHERE clause is going to require the expression to be evaluated for every row in the table.  Given a range of date values we are looking for, if the information was stored in a DATETIME column, with an appropriate index defined, the optimizer could make use of a range scan operation.

Which leads us to the conclusion that for performance, MEDIUMTEXT is not the best datatype for storing DATETIME values.

Comment: Thank you so much for solution. ANd yes, mediumtext is not ideal for saving date